# UNC location access using C#.net

Tags: c#

We are using C#.net application to access UNC location/Shared Server location.we used below function to connect to UNC location with username & password.

Note: we have Prallel process using below function, that mean at time 20 machines are accessing same UNC location with same UserName & Password using below Method.

Issue is : We receive 'Number of connection exceeds to that machine' error.

```
USE_INFO_2 useinfo = new USE_INFO_2();

useinfo.ui2_remote = UNCPath;
useinfo.ui2_username = User;
useinfo.ui2_domainname = Domain;
useinfo.ui2_password = Password;
useinfo.ui2_asg_type = 0;
useinfo.ui2_usecount = 1;
uint paramErrorIndex;
returncode = NetUseAdd(null, 2, ref useinfo, out paramErrorIndex);
```

Any one has any idea on that, how to resolve the same?

Comment: any one have any idea to resolve above issue ?

Comment: is there any idea about error , how can i  reproduce it ?